# Metamask-Web3 error while running Truffle-react-box development server

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, truffle, metamask

When I run the server using npm run start, the webpage keeps on refreshing with this error -

[image]

**The App.js -**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  runExample = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;

    // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
    await contract.methods.set(5).send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

    // Update state with the result.
    this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Good to Go!</h1>
        <p>Your Truffle Box is installed and ready.</p>
        <h2>Smart Contract Example</h2>
        <p>
          If your contracts compiled and migrated successfully, below will show
          a stored value of 5 (by default).
        </p>
        <p>
          Try changing the value stored on <strong>line 40</strong> of App.js.
        </p>
        <div>The stored value is: {this.state.storageValue}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried re-installing Metamask, but no luck! I don't know what another web3 means here, I just have one web3 i.e., the one included in the project itself -

**Here is the package.json file -**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "web3": "1.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```